# re.search searches for last part of the string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

so i am using re.search function to search for a substring, problem is at the end of the string there is repeating data and i only want to search to the first dataset declared

here is the code

```
file = open ("flash-ori", "rb").read().hex()

DTC_data = re.search("0080040004000100(.*)010202010202020202020202", file)

print (DTC_data.group())
```

here is what i get

```
0080040004000100**DATA**01020201020202020202020202020202010202020102020202010202020202020202020102020202020a0202020202020202020202020a02020102020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020101010102020101010102020101010102020101010102020101010101020201010101010202010102010101020202010102010101020202010202020102020201020202020102020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202020202010202010202010202010202010202020202010202020202010202020202010202020202020202020202020201020201020201020201020
```

here is what i want to do

```
0080040004000100**DATA**010202010202020202020202
```

all solutions much appritiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, regex quantifiers are greedy; they'll take as much as they possibly can when you give a `.*` for instance. You can switch to non-greedy mode by appending a `?`, making the regex:

```
r"0080040004000100(.*?)010202010202020202020202"
```

Note also that I added a leading `r` to make this a raw string literal. It makes no difference at all here, but it's a good idea to use raw string literals exclusively for regular expressions, as failing to do so will eventually bite you, e.g. when you want a word boundary, `r'\b'`, and search for the ASCII backspace character `'\b'`.

Comment: thanks solved and noted

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to:

```
DTC_data = re.search("0080040004000100(.*?)010202010202020202020202", file)
```

The `?` will make it non-greedy.

Comment: @LiquidT You are welcome :)